# Why iPhone chrome file input file name always image.jpeg?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, file, google-chrome

I have a web application which upload files from browser. For iPhone Google chrome, The file input control always return the same file name "image.jpeg". Please open this link in iPhone chrome: http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljxenmhs/files_1.htm

whatever files (I think pictures only), the file names are always `image.jpeg`, why is this happening?

Comment: What name would you expect? It is not like you have a file browser on the iPhone where you can name image files

Comment: I would expect the same file name as is on the iPhone file system.